# C - Problems with strcat

Tags: c, strcat

I'm trying to get the user argv and print in the screen the result. Here is my following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc >= 1)
    {
        char *command = "gcc ";
        strcat(command, argv[1]);
        printf("%s", command);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

It compiles, but every time I execute it says that "Windows stoped to work". Basically, if the user does:

```
myprogram.exe test
```

the output might be

```
gcc test
```

Where is my error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need your destination argument to strcat to be large enough to hold everything, ie

```
char command[50];
strcpy(command, "gcc ");
strcat(command, argv[1]);
```

Comment: It worked with 5001 instead of 50. Thank you

Comment: Keep in mind the other answers with dynamic allocation - you may eventually get some input that will *not* fit into an array of 5001 :)

Comment: This causes undefined behaviour; `strcat` appends to an existing string but `command` is uninitialized. You should either start with `strcpy`, or initialize `command[0]` at least to `0`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate memory to the char pointer before using strcat. Because char *command = "gcc" will be just pointing to a memory location. Before writing in that location you will have to allocate memory using malloc or change it to an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
char *command
```

just declares an array without pointing to any space. You need to allocate space to the pointer before using it or you can use character array.

```
char command[100]="string";
```

or

```
 char *command = (char*) malloc (size);
```

And then you can use strcat like you have used.

Comment: `char *command;` declares a pointer, not an array.  Also, OP's code actually does point it to some space. And don't cast malloc.

Comment: Why shouldn't malloc be cast?

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). The cast has zero good effects and non-zero bad effects.